# Class cast exception when i try to cast getAttribute from the session object?

Tags: java

I know it is possible without any exceptions being thrown but how can i cast this object/bean:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
private HashMap<String, Item> items;
private String owner;

public ShoppingCart(String owner) {
    items = new HashMap<String, Item>();
    this.owner = owner;
}

public class Servlet extends HttpServletRequest request

         if (action.equals("/addItem")) {
                //if()
                String Id = request.getParameter("itemId");
                ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("cart");
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity").toString());
                Item item = this.stock.getItem(Id);
                cart.addItem(item, quantity);
                dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(action = "/CartView.jspx");
            }
```

Shopping cart cast throws class cast exception cannot cast string to model type lessonSelection. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you add cart attribute to session?

Comment: session.setAttribute("cart", username);

Comment: Apparently you're casting a thing as if it were a ShoppingCart, and... it isn't. So... don't do that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast, or do you just need to call the constructor:  new ShoppingCart (session.getAttribute ("cart"));

Comment: It looks like the attribute you stored in ur session is not a type of Shopping cart. Cast it to type object, and test to see if it's instance of Shopping cart. if(o instanceof ShopingCart){}

Comment: Is username a String?

Comment: yes it is. it maybe a session problem after alll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a `String` object inside session with `session.setAttribute("cart", username);` but you are later trying to cast this `String` to `ShoppingCart` . It is normal that `String` can not be casted to `ShoppingCart` so it gives a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: can i pass two variables to one session like this: session.setAttribute("cart",Username,cart) or something similar?

Comment: @RamiStefanidis OP mentioned it on the comment section.

Comment: @AkashKing I think you should define a user class which has a cart field. Then you can use session.setAttribute("cart", user.cart)

Comment: @RamiStefanidis OP confirmed username as String in the comments.

Comment: is it possible to pass two variables in one session object?

Comment: I think it is not possible. In my example you are storing the cart field of user object not two variables